# List navigation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Why I have to press 2 times the arrow key down to get a navigation through the list items in a list component of Flash?

There´s any workaround for this?

I have a listener for keyboard event that checks if keyCode is equal to 40 if it is then I use 'stage.focus = list', but I have to press 2 times key arrow down to start navigating through list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your set up the first time you press the arrow down key the focus is set on the list component (you'll see a blue outline on the component), and the second time you press the key the list actually has focus and reacts. If you want it to react right away just give it focus from the beginning, `stage.focus = list` on your main timeline instead the addEventListener should be fine assuming `list` is the instance name of your List component.